# No route matches..prefixed controller in kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I have a route that is being prefixed from Kaminari within an engine view

The route is

```
  resources :series_valuations, only: [:index]
```

The Kaminari paginate route throws:
    No route matches {:controller=>"fc_rseries/series_valuations", :active_tab=>"Calcs", :page=>nil}

Setting `paginate @objs, params: {controller: "series_valuations"}` doesn't work in the view.

How do I create a route to catch the above? I tried:

```
match "fc_rseries/series_valuations", controller: 'series_valuations', action: 'index'
```

but it doesn't catch it

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your route to use scope.

```
scope module: 'fc_rseries' do
  resources :series_valuations, only: [:index]
end
```

Comment: Thanks but routes are already scoped. FcRseries::Engine.routes.draw do

Comment: I think it might have been a kaminari issue that was resolved @Chris. What's your error?